# How to Force SSL to Specific Named Route in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redirect, https

I have a Rails Application in which I have used force_ssl method as

```
def force_ssl # to use https for payment page
  if !Rails.env.development? && !request.ssl?
    redirect_to :protocol => 'https'
  end
end
```

for a Particular action name 'abc' with named route

match '/find-a-abc' => "home#abc"

when I go to URL

http://local.demo.com/find-a-abc

it will redirect_to https://local.demo.com/abc

Any Solution? so it will redirect_to Particular route, rather than redirecting to an Action when using a https Protocol.

Comment: Would defining `force_ssl` as a `before_filter` work?

Comment: Yes it work perfectly, but mine problem is it redirecting to action instead of named path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you've provided a named route here (i.e. `match '/find-a-abc' => "home#abc", :as => :named_route`). You will need to do this and call `named_route_url` rather than just the controller and action to get the right URL.

If you want a specific route to always be handled with SSL, you could define the route like so:

```
scope :protocol => 'https://', :constraints => { :protocol => 'https://' } do
  match '/find-a-abc' => "home#abc", :as => :abc
end
```

Then `abc_url` should always be "https://local.demo.com/find-a-abc"